# Sum of All Total related to a Vulnerability Name

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query

```
 SELECT Year(outertblissues.opendt)        AS Years,
       Month(outertblissues.opendt)       AS Months,
       outertblvulnerability.vulname,
       Count(outertblvulnerability.vulid) Vulcount
FROM   tbl_apptestdetails AS outertblapptestdetails
       INNER JOIN tbl_applicationlist AS outertblapplicationlist
               ON outertblapptestdetails.appid = outertblapplicationlist.appid
       INNER JOIN tbl_bu AS outertblbu
               ON outertblbu.buid = outertblapplicationlist.buid
       INNER JOIN tbl_issues AS outertblissues
               ON outertblapptestdetails.testdetailid =
                  outertblissues.testdetailid
                  AND outertblissues.status NOT IN( '1', '4' )
       INNER JOIN tbl_vulnerability AS outertblvulnerability
               ON outertblissues.vulid = outertblvulnerability.vulid
GROUP  BY Year(outertblissues.opendt),
          Month(outertblissues.opendt),
          outertblvulnerability.vulname
ORDER  BY vulcount DESC
```

Which gives the following result
[image]

Now a want one more column Name as SumOfCount which gives the Sum of all VulCount Related to a particular VulName For example in front of "Additional Issues" The SumOfCount Should be 8 , Similarly for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Sql Server 2012 or higher you can try instruction Sum() over partition by

```
SUM(VulCount) OVER(PARTITION BY  VulName)
```

Comment: @Henry the first solution worked for me, please remove the second query and i will mark it as answer , Big thanks to you